# AngularJS $http.get send same xhr request twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angular-ui-router

In my app I'm using [Angularjs-gulp-browserify-boilerplate](https://github.com/jakemmarsh/angularjs-gulp-browserify-boilerplate.git)

In my service I have next code:

```
function ResourceService($http, AppSettings) {
    'ngInject';

    const service = {};

    service.getResource = function(params) {
        console.log('Get resource')
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            $http.get(AppSettings.apiUrl + 'v1/resorce')).then((resp) => {                
                resolve(resp);
            }).catch((err, status) => {
                reject(err, status);
            });
        });
    };
```

In controller:

```
function ResourceCtrl(BidService) {
    'ngInject';

    // ViewModel
    const vm = this;
    ResourceService.getResource().then((res) => {        
         vm.items = res.data;
    });

}
export default {
    name: 'ResourceCtrl',
    fn: ResourceCtrl
};
```

In dev console:
[image: Result of call getResource]

How to prevent query duplication ?

Comment: Can you please double check `ResourceCtrl` has been mentioned on view only once? Perhaps it could loaded once again from routing configuration(just a guess).

Comment: ResourceCtrl loading once from config(ui-router), but it is using as nested controller FE:
account
account.resources --> xhr 1 time.
account.resources.resource --> xhr 2 times.

Answer (score 1):

By default `$http` return a promise. so you do not need to create a promise again to resolve it. Just return the request from the service and resolve the promise from controller.

```
 service.getResource = function(params) {
        console.log('Get resource')
        return $http.get(AppSettings.apiUrl + 'v1/resorce'))
 };
```

controller

```
ResourceService.getResource()
  .then((res) => {        
         vm.items = res.data;
  }).catch((res) => {
    console.log(res.data)
  });
```

Comment: It is not prevents xhr duplication